# UITableView insertion animation not displaying properly(?)

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, animation, uikit

I'm struggling to get the insertion animation I want, at least what should happen isn't happening, I can't see what I'm doing wrong.
Using the .Bottom and .Top UITableViewRowAnimations with insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation: don't produce the animations I expect. They both seem to affect the cell above or below the one I specify.

Can anyone please explain why (I may be mistaken)?

Here is all the relevant code:

```
@IBAction func add(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    model.pots.insert(Pot(name: "test", initial: 0, creationDate: NSDate(), startDate: NSDate(), expenditure: [], regularTopUps: [], extraTopUps: []), atIndex: 1)
    tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forItem: 1, inSection: 0)], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Bottom)
}
```

So for instance in this example, I would expect the new cell to slide in from beneath cell 0 and push cells 1-2 downward and take the cell 1 position. What actually happens is that the new cell takes the 1 position instantaneously and then the previous cells 1-2 slide down with the old cell 1 coming in from underneath the new cell.
The funny thing is that if I instead use

```
@IBAction func add(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    model.pots.insert(Pot(name: "test", initial: 0, creationDate: NSDate(), startDate: NSDate(), expenditure: [], regularTopUps: [], extraTopUps: []), atIndex: 1)
    tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forItem: 0, inSection: 0)], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Bottom)
}
```

I get roughly the behaviour I expect.
I have a similar problem with the .Top animation, but I don't think I have one with any of the others.

Help greatly appreciated.

Comment: What happens if you use `UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic` - do you like that any better?

Comment: What happens if you wrap it in `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates`? Does that make any difference?

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
.Automatic just chooses .Top for me and the effect is no different.
I see no difference at all using the begin/endUpdates commands.